# Conexión a mysql por php y mostrar en html responsive

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, xampp

Quiero conectarme a una db donde tengo registros (16 en total). Los quiero mostrar en una tabla html responsive con un botón de imprimir, cuando hago la conexión:

```
// Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "consulta";
    $password = "12345";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "consulta";

// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

// Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
// establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM consulta";
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
```

Tengo la respuesta de error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'consulta'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\consulta\consulta1.php on line 24
>   No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos

¿Cuál puede ser mi error? ya que probe sin tablas una db y me dice, "exito, conectado a la base de datos, pero al cargar y querer mostrar en html ya no corre nada... :/

Comment: Podría considerarse un error de sintaxis no haber puesto la contraseña: `$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" )` quizá debería ser `$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password )`.

Comment: Yo también ando aprendiendo PHP y me recomendaron usar PDO y sentencias preparadas para evitar las inyecciones sql

Comment: @AbelJM, mysqli también soporta consultas preparadas: [http://php.net/mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, he conseguido conectarme!

Comment: Hola @ivan , si alguna de las respuestas te ayudó a solucionar el problema te agradecería que marcaras aquella que te fue más útil como correcta (debes pulsar en la marca ✔ que hay a la izquierda de las respuestas).

Answer (score 1):

El error no tiene nada que ver con dar salida de HTML adaptativo ni nada por el estilo. Fíjate bien en el mensaje de error:

> Access denied for user 'consulta'@'localhost' (**using password: NO**)

Te está diciendo que NO has usado contraseña para acceder al servidor MySQL.

Si te das cuenta no llegas a usar la contraseña durante la conexión, usas una cadena en blanco (`""`) en su lugar:

```
// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" )
  or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
```

La forma correcta, usando la contraseña, sería:

```
// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $pasword )
  or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error de conexión**

Como ya te han comentado en alguna otra respuesta, no estas accediendo con una contraseña.

De todas maneras, si te fijas en el error que te da, es el que has definido tu en la linea de conexión. Por lo que con eso deberías de saber que el problema lo tienes en esa sentencia.

**Responsive**

Siento decirte que esto no tiene nada que ver con los datos que imprimas o como los imprimas. Esto se usa consigue con un lenguaje de estilos como css.

Echale un vistazo a este [articulo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) en ingles sobre que es responsive.

**Impresion**

Por último, y decirte que no todo son pegas ;P.

Utiliza [print](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp).

```
window.print();
```

El metodo print imprime la pantalla actual. Abrira el tipico menu opciones de impresion y todo lo demas a costa de los usuarios :)

Por si no lo sabes, para que el boton llame a la función, usa `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

No estas poniendo la contraseña en tu **conexión** a la base de datos, solo pusiste comillas **""** debería ser así:

```
// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
```